# Is it possible to change string representation of a `typing.TypedDict`?

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing

I can do it while subclassing from a native `dict` but can't with the typed version. Here's the code:

```py
from typing import TypedDict


class Typed(TypedDict):
    x: int

    def __str__(self):
        return "str-typed"


class Native(dict):
    def __str__(self):
        return "str-native"


typed = Typed(x=1)
print("typed =", typed)

native = Native(x=1)
print("native =", native)

assert typed == native
```

and its result:

```sh
$ python typed_dict.py 
typed = {'x': 1}
native = str-native

$ mypy typed_dict.py 
typed_dict.py:7: error: Invalid statement in TypedDict definition; expected "field_name: field_type"
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calling `Typed` creates a regular dict. Methods you write won't do anything, because `typed` isn't an instance of `Typed` and doesn't have any of `Typed`'s methods.

While it is technically possible to disable that behavior at runtime (in the current 3.8 implementation, `del Typed.__new__` would do it), mypy still won't be happy. The intent of `TypedDict` is that

```
class Foo(typing.TypedDict):
    x: int
    y: str

d: Foo = {'x': 1, 'y': 'blah'}
```

type checks. A `TypedDict` subclass is intended to represent a static type for *regular dicts* with specific string keys. It's not supposed to be used as its own separate runtime type.

Also, `del Typed.__new__` would be poking at implementation details, which are subject to change without notice.

Comment: I think it's useful to point to [PEP 589](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0589/) too. :-)